# How to reduce an expression into user-defined variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, algebra

In the following code, I define a set of matrices. Then, I define a function that calculates the commutation relation relation between these matrices

```
Subscript[T, 1] = 1/2 ({
     {0, 1, 0},
     {1, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0}
    });
Subscript[T, 2] = 1/2 ({
     {0, -I, 0},
     {I, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0}
    });
Subscript[T, z 
  ] = 1/2 ({
     {1, 0, 0},
     {0, -1, 0},
     {0, 0, 0}
    });
Subscript[V, 1
  ] = 1/2 ({
     {0, 0, 1},
     {0, 0, 0},
     {1, 0, 0}
    });
Subscript[V, 2 
  ] = 1/2 ({
     {0, 0, -I},
     {0, 0, 0},
     {I, 0, 0}
    });
Subscript[U, 1 ] = 1/2 ({
     {0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 1},
     {0, 1, 0}
    });
Subscript[U, 2 ] = 1/2 ({
     {0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, -I},
     {0, I, 0}
    });
Y = 1/3 ({
     {1, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, -2}
    });
Subscript[T, a] = Subscript[T, 1] + I Subscript[T, 2];
Subscript[T, b] = Subscript[T, 1] - I Subscript[T, 2];
Subscript[V, a] = Subscript[V, 1] + I Subscript[V, 2];
Subscript[V, b] = Subscript[V, 1] - I Subscript[V, 2];
Subscript[U, a] = Subscript[U, 1] + I Subscript[U, 2];
Subscript[U, b] = Subscript[U, 1] - I Subscript[U, 2];
generators = {Subscript[T, a], Subscript[T, b], Subscript[T, z], 
   Subscript[U, a], Subscript[U, b], Subscript[V, a], Subscript[V, b],
    Y};
commutator[x_, y_] = x.y - y.x;
commutator[Subscript[T, a],Subscript[T, b]]
```

Now, the commutator between the matrix $T_a$ and $T_b$ turns out to be 2$T_z$. It explicitly calculates the result as expected but I want it to write in terms of my variables.

I wish to write 16 such commutation relations in a table column. I'm using the additional code below to generate the table of matrices. I wish to replace them with my variables.

```
   generators = {Subscript[T, a], Subscript[T, b], Subscript[T, z], 
   Subscript[U, a], Subscript[U, b], Subscript[V, a], Subscript[V, b],
    Y};
    relationsTable = 
      Table[MatrixForm[commutator[i, j]], {i, generators}, {j, 
        generators}];
    header1 = 
      Prepend[relationsTable, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(a\)]\)", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(b\)]\)", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(z\)]\)", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(a\)]\)", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(b\)]\)", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(a\)]\)", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(b\)]\)", "Y"}];
    column1 = 
      MapThread[
       Prepend, {header1, {"", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(a\)]\)", 
         "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(b\)]\)", 
         "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(z\)]\)", 
         "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(a\)]\)", 
         "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(b\)]\)", 
         "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(a\)]\)", 
         "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(b\)]\)", "Y"}}];
    Grid[column1, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

How do i go about replacing the elemts of this table with the variables that I've defined above?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome! 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thank you for this kind reminder Lou. I shall keep this in mind!

Comment: What is the definition of `generators`? - is it the list of matrices that you've written? Is the commutator defined as `A.B - B.A`? What is `"Y"`? What are `header1` and `column` supposed to be? Why do you say there are 16 such commutation relations when you have 7 matrices defined, and therefore there are 28 different possible pairs of matrices with which to form commutators?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got the number wrong. It isn't 16, its 64 to be precise. I've attached an image of the result as well now. Also, I've included the generators definition!

Comment: Okay. I think you can take advantage of the fact that your matrices are orthogonal under the trace product `Tr[ConjugateTranspose[a].b]`, and use that fact to select from the symbols. I will work on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Preamble

You should be able to adapt this solution to your specific case, but I have taken the liberty of altering your code somewhat and even changing the definitions of some of the matrices. I will explain why I did what I did so that you can alter things to fit with your definitions.

**Main alterations:**

- Instead of `Set`ting the values of your `Subscript`ed symbols, I am using a list of replacement rules that we can use to replace the `Subscript`ed symbols with the corresponding matrices. There are two reasons for this. First, it allows us to use the `Subscript`ed symbols for formatting, making it so that they are not automatically replaced by the corresponding matrices. Second, there are essentially no computational use-cases for `Subscript`, and I recommend *only* using `Subscript`s for formatting purposes. Never use them to name your variables, because unless you are familiar with `DownValues`, `UpValues`, and so on, they might act strangely.
- I have re-scaled some of your matrix definitions (for instance `Subscript[T, z]`) in order to make the algebra easier. In particular, we want a set of normalized (under the trace-norm) basis vectors, so I have re-scaled to make this happen.

Note that at the end of the post is the fix that allows you to use your original definitions.

### Solution

The big idea is to use the facts that (1) the set of generators compose a basis for the set of traceless 3-by-3 matrices that is orthonormal under the trace norm, and (2) the commutators of the generators can always be expanded in the generators, because the trace of a commutator is always zero. Basically we compute the expansion coefficients of the commutators of the generators in the generator-basis by using the trace-inner-product.

Here is the list of replacement rules (note that I have re-scaled both `Subscript[T, z]` and `Y`):

```
Clear["Subscript"]
rules = {
  Subscript[T, 1] -> 1/2 ({{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}})
  , Subscript[T, 2] -> 1/2 ({{0, -I, 0}, {I, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}})
  , Subscript[T, z] -> 1/Sqrt[2] ({{1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}})
  , Subscript[V, 1] -> 1/2 ({{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}})
  , Subscript[V, 2] -> 1/2 ({{0, 0, -I}, {0, 0, 0}, {I, 0, 0}})
  , Subscript[U, 1] -> 1/2 ({{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}})
  , Subscript[U, 2] -> 1/2 ({{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -I}, {0, I, 0}})
  , Y -> 1/Sqrt[6] ({{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -2}})
  , Subscript[T, a] -> Subscript[T, 1] + I Subscript[T, 2]
  , Subscript[T, b] -> Subscript[T, 1] - I Subscript[T, 2]
  , Subscript[V, a] -> Subscript[V, 1] + I Subscript[V, 2]
  , Subscript[V, b] -> Subscript[V, 1] - I Subscript[V, 2]
  , Subscript[U, a] -> Subscript[U, 1] + I Subscript[U, 2]
  , Subscript[U, b] -> Subscript[U, 1] - I Subscript[U, 2]};
```

I also include your definitions,

```
generators = {Subscript[T, a], Subscript[T, b], Subscript[T, z], Subscript[U, a]
            , Subscript[U, b], Subscript[V, a], Subscript[V, b], Y};
commutator[x_, y_] = x.y - y.x;
```

Finally, we define the inner product on this space of matrices as

```
traceProduct[a_, b_] := Tr[ConjugateTranspose[a].b]
```

Note that the set of generators is an orthonormal basis for the space of traceless 3-by-3 matrices under this norm:

```
Outer[traceProduct[#1, #2] &, generators //. rules, generators //. rules, 1]
```

yields the identity matrix.

We now generate all of the commutators of the generators using

```
comms = Outer[commutator[#1, #2] &, generators //. rules, generators //. rules, 1];
```

For each of the elements in this 8-by-8 matrix of 3-by-3 matrices, we compute the expansion coefficients in the generator-basis using

```
symbols = generators.Outer[traceProduct[#1, #2] &, generators //. rules, comms, 1, 2] // Simplify;
TableForm[symbols, TableHeadings -> {generators, generators}]
```

results in

[image]

### Verifying the solution

Finally, we can verify that the calculation has been done correctly by taking the matrix of `symbols`, applying `rules` to it, and comparing it to the original `comms`:

```
Equal[symbols /. (0 -> ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}]) //. rules // Simplify, comms]
(* True *)
```

### How to fix the solution so that the original definitions work

The following fix should work. Define the squared-norms of the generators as

```
norms = traceProduct[#, #] & /@ generators //. rules;
```

Then, the definition of `symbols` is modified to

```
symbols = (generators/norms).Outer[traceProduct[#1, #2] &, generators //. rules, comms, 1, 2] // Simplify;
TableForm[symbols, TableHeadings -> {generators, generators}]
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot march! I'll have to go through your answer more thoroughly but thanks for the effort! Much appreciated! :)